# Read contents of file from .zip file in swift

Tags: ios, swift, gzip

How to read the contents of a file with **.zip** extension in `swift`

I am having an **.zip** file made from gZip I need to read the contents of the **.zip** file without unzipping the file

```
let zipData = NSData(contentsOfFile: zipfilePath) as Data?
```

Without using third party libraries

Comment: Try to write your own decoder :)) . Or at least look into the existing code, see what means to deflate a zip, how to read chunks of data etc... How to detect header info and so many more things

Answer (score 0):

```
".gz file made from gZip"

import Gzip

let ZipFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Your-File-Name", ofType: "gz")
print(ZipFile as Any)

let Data = NSData(contentsOfFile: ZipFile!) as Data?

let decompressedData: Data
if Data!.isGzipped {
    decompressedData = try! Data!.gunzipped()
} else {
    decompressedData = Data!
}

var Decompress_String = ""
if let string = String(bytes: decompressedData, encoding: .utf8) {
    Decompress_String = string
} else {
    print("not a valid UTF-8 sequence")
}

print("Decompress_String")
```

Comment: Zip and gzip are two different things. Zip is an archival tool and inside a zip file you can have entire directories and files.